# Showing status of Hive query in PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm running a Hive query from a sparksession (`spark`)

`spark.sql('SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE').show()`

Is there a argument in the sql function, or a configuration to print the status akin to what is displayed in Hive cli?

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1193; number of reducers: 1099
2017-05-16 14:54:38,165 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-05-16 14:54:49,625 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 213.84 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:50,678 Stage-1 map = 13%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4495.91 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:51,729 Stage-1 map = 15%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 5081.18 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:52,778 Stage-1 map = 17%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 5244.48 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:53,818 Stage-1 map = 34%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7186.78 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:54,851 Stage-1 map = 46%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7702.71 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:55,887 Stage-1 map = 51%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7968.09 sec
2017-05-16 14:54:56,919 Stage-1 map = 54%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 8325.11 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view the status in a couple ways.

1) to view a [fairly verbose] status of the job as it's running, change the logLevel to "INFO": `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")`

2) Using the Spark or YARN UI (usually port 18088 for Spark or 4040 for local and 8088 for YARN)

The event logs in the UI will show you what you need to know or the progress bars are a simpler visual.

Relevant doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html